# Как получить url из строки?

Tags: строки, golang, url

Есть строка:

```
str := "Welcome! https://google.com/reports.html get up "
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из этой строки получить только url **https://google.com**?

Comment: можно регуляркой (модуль regexp) вытащить url. Например такой: `(https?://.+\.\w+)`. На питоне получилось: `>>> re.findall('(https?://.+\.\w+)',"Welcome! https://google.com get up ")
['https://google.com']`

Comment: Благодарю! Но мне необходимо чтобы url заканчивался не / а пробелом. Т.е. у меня получается если строка чуть длиннее "https://google.com/reports.html" выводит только "https://google.com". Дополнил в вопросе

Comment: допишите регулярку, добавьте в ней что может быть слеш :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно разделить `s := strings.Split(strUrls," ")` и проверить

```
for k,v = range s {
    strings.Contains(v, "http")
}
```